# How to get the values from specific Xelement based on condition in linq

Tags: xml, linq, lambda

```
` <waypoints>
    <waypoint>
      <properties>
        <property value="2.935860e+002" name="RangeAway" />
        <property value="2.000000e+000" name="Keel Clearance" />
        <property value="1" name="Display Name" />
        <property value="" name="OtherCharts" />
        <property value="0.000000e+000" name="ROT" />
        <property value="0" name="Stop Time" />
        <property value="-1.000000e+000" name="TTG" />
        <property value="0" name="NavWatchLevel" />
        <property value="2.271720e+002" name="BearingTo" />
        <property value="" name="BACharts" />
        <property value="1" name="TTG Calc" />
        <property value="1.000000e+001" name="SOG" />
        <property value="0" name="Locked" />
        <property value="0" name="Engine Status" />
        <property value="1" name="Max Position Fix" />
        <property value="0" name="Display Description" />
        <property value="5.000000e-001" name="Turn Radius" />
        <property value="0" name="Activate" />
        <property value="0" name="Type" />
        <property value="" name="ReferencePoint" />
        <property value="2.935860e+002" name="RangeTo" />
        <property value="38 28.346N" name="Latitude" />
        <property value="1" name="Leg Type" />
        <property value="1.000000e-001" name="Port XTE" />
        <property value="WP_001" name="Name" />
        <property value="-1.000000e+000" name="TIME Zone" />
        <property value="0" name="PilotSign" />
        <property value="2.271720e+002" name="BearingAway" />
        <property value="51025A43-BBC9-4E95-8E92-84AF4E6AC872" name="ID" />
        <property value="" name="PassingTime" />
        <property value="0" name="Index" />
        <property value="1.000000e-001" name="Stbd XTE" />
        <property value="N/A" name="ETA" />
        <property value="009 22.978W" name="Longitude" />
      </properties>
      <description />
    </waypoint>
    <waypoint>
      <properties>
        <property value="4.365710e+002" name="RangeAway" />
        <property value="2.000000e+000" name="Keel Clearance" />
        <property value="1" name="Display Name" />
        <property value="" name="OtherCharts" />
        <property value="1.909859e+001" name="ROT" />
        <property value="0" name="Stop Time" />
        <property value="2.935860e+001" name="TTG" />
        <property value="0" name="NavWatchLevel" />
        <property value="2.131972e+002" name="BearingTo" />
        <property value="" name="BACharts" />
        <property value="1" name="TTG Calc" />
        <property value="1.000000e+001" name="SOG" />
        <property value="0" name="Locked" />
        <property value="0" name="Engine Status" />
        <property value="1" name="Max Position Fix" />
        <property value="0" name="Display Description" />
        <property value="5.000000e-001" name="Turn Radius" />
        <property value="0" name="Activate" />
        <property value="0" name="Type" />
        <property value="" name="ReferencePoint" />
        <property value="4.365710e+002" name="RangeTo" />
        <property value="35 08.505N" name="Latitude" />
        <property value="1" name="Leg Type" />
        <property value="1.000000e-001" name="Port XTE" />
        <property value="WP_002" name="Name" />
        <property value="-1.000000e+000" name="TIME Zone" />
        <property value="0" name="PilotSign" />
        <property value="2.131972e+002" name="BearingAway" />
        <property value="51025A43-BBC9-4E95-8E92-84AF4E6AC872" name="ID" />
        <property value="" name="PassingTime" />
        <property value="1" name="Index" />
        <property value="1.000000e-001" name="Stbd XTE" />
        <property value="01/08 21:11:17(+01)" name="ETA" />
        <property value="013 51.175W" name="Longitude" />
      </properties>
      <description />
    </waypoint>
</waypoints>`
```

I have a file as above and I want to get the values of those Xelements whose name attribute includes "Latitude","Longitude","Turn Radius","BearingTo","RangeTo" , and assign those values to different properties of an object. The object has properties similar to value of name attribute. 
The file has 9  nodes, so I should be able to generate 9 objects out of this file.
I have tried this

```
var wayPointCollection = (from property in properties where property.LastAttribute.Value.Equals("Latitude") 
select new LocationEntity
{
    LATITUDE = (property.FirstAttribute.Value)
}
```

But in my approach I can only check one attribute and get value associated with it. How can achieve the goal with LINQ or Lambda.

Comment: What is `properties` here? How do you get from XML to that? And what is `r`?

Comment: @DavidG the properties represent the node in xml and property is child element of properties. I am using Xdoc and getting to properties which is stored in a var type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use LINQ to XML to collect each waypoint and convert its properties into a `Dictionary` so you can retrieve the ones you want:

```
var ans = xd.Descendants("waypoint")
            .Select(wp => {
                var wpd = wp.Descendants("property")
                            .ToDictionary(wpp => wpp.Attribute("name").Value, wpp => wpp.Attribute("value").Value);
                return new LocationEntity {
                    Latitude = wpd["Latitude"],
                    Longitude = wpd["Longitude"],
                    TurnRadius = wpd["Turn Radius"],
                    BearingTo = wpd["BearingTo"],
                    RangeTo = wpd["RangeTo"]
                };
            });
```

`ans` will be a `List<LocationEntity>` that contains all the converted waypoints.

Alternatively, you could create a helper class that searches the property descendants to retrieve attribute values:

```
public class XMLWaypoint {
    IEnumerable<XElement> xmlwp;

    public XMLWaypoint(XElement x) {
        xmlwp = x.Descendants("property");
    }

    public string this[string propName]
    {
        get
        {
            return xmlwp.FirstOrDefault(wpp => wpp.Attribute("name").Value == propName)?.Attribute("value").Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you could use this to lookup each attribute as needed:

```
var ans2 = xd.Descendants("waypoint")
             .Select(wp => {
                 var xwp = new XMLWaypoint(wp);

                 return new LocationEntity {
                     Latitude = xwp["Latitude"],
                     Longitude = xwp["Longitude"],
                     TurnRadius = xwp["Turn Radius"],
                     BearingTo = xwp["BearingTo"],
                     RangeTo = xwp["RangeTo"]
                 };
             });
```

You could also create a method that uses Reflection to automatically map to properties in an object but that seems like overkill, plus you have the issue of property names not matching object property names (e.g. "Turn Radius"). It does make me think an interesting extension to LINQ to XML would be an Entity Framework for XML, though.

Comment: In your second approach there are few errors i tried searching but couldnt figure it out as I am new to it. Here they are                                                                    
 `error CS1002: ; expected
 error CS1519: Invalid token '=>' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
 error CS1519: Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
 error CS1519: Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration`

Comment: @shrinath What version of Visual Studio / C# are you using? I am using an [expression-bodied member](https://davefancher.com/2014/08/25/c-6-0-expression-bodied-members/) there.

Comment: It is VisualStudio17, I am working on ASPNET core 2.0.2, and have .net framework 4.6 installed which means It is c# 6

Comment: @shrinath You can replace the expression bodied member with a full blown `get` property definition instead.

Comment: Okay I will look into that. Thanks.

Comment: @shrinath I changed my code to use a normal constructor, I think expression bodied constructors are a C# 7 feature.

Comment: **@NetMage** okay. Which approach would be efficient to use considering performance of application or it doesnt matter I can go with anyone. I Appreciate your support.

Comment: @shrinath That really depends on a lot of factors, including how many waypoints you are processing. With about 200,000 waypoints, the `Dictionary` approach is about 0.4 seconds faster on my PC. OTOH, if your program needs to do more with the XML, creating a custom XMLWaypoint object might offer other advantages, for example you could encapsulate `LocationEntity` creation as a method in the class.

Comment: @shrinath In fact, modifying `XMLWaypoint` to compute and store the `Dictionary` and use that for the indexed property makes the speed a wash as well. Then its a matter of how much garbage collection and object creation / memory matter to you, which may also depend on how many waypoints you are processing.